# Get multiple data in to single column from two table using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables :

**user**

Table User

```
 Id      Name             
 1       Jhon             
 2       Andy
```

**book**

```
  Id    book       user_id
   1    English       1
   2    Physics       1
```

I want data as

```
array
(
   [id]=>1,[name]=>Jhon,
   [books]=>'English,Physics'
)
```

Is it possible by MYSQL, If yes then please help me. i cann't figure it out how to do this using MYSQL query. Thanks in advance. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select
u.id,
u.name,
group_concat(b.book) as book
from user u
join book b on b.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
```

If you need the books to be ordered then use

```
group_concat(b.book order by b.book) as book
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. But this query concating all books in same column means books which associated with other users

Comment: Did you add `group by u.id` at the end ?